# Received an invalid column length from the bcp client in spark job

Tags: sql-server, database, apache-spark, pyspark

I am playing around with spark and wanted to store a data frame in a sql database. It works but not when saving a datetime column:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,Row
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType,TimestampType,StructType,StructField,StringType
from datetime import datetime

...

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    ...
    .getOrCreate()
    
# Create DataFrame 

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    Row(id=1, title='string1', created_at=datetime.now())
])

schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("title", StringType(), False),
    StructField("created_at", TimestampType(), True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

df.show()

try:
  df.write \
    .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("truncate", True) \
    .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .option("user", username) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .save()
except ValueError as error :
    print("Connector write failed", error)
```

Schema:

[image]

Error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid 3
```

From my understanding the error states that datetime.now() has invalid length. But how can that be, if it is a standard datetime? Any ideas what the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are problems with the code to create the dataframe.  You are missing libraries.  The code below creates the dataframe correctly.

```
#
#  1 - Make test dataframe
#

# libraries
from pyspark.sql import Row
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, TimestampType

# create rdd
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([Row(id=1, title='string1', created_at=datetime.now())])

# define structure
schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("title", StringType(), False),
    StructField("created_at", TimestampType(), True)
])

# create df
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

# show df
display(df)
```

[image]

The output is shown above.  We need to create a table that follows the nullability and data types.

The code below creates a table called stack_overflow.

```
-- drop table
drop table if exists stack_overflow
go

-- create table
create table stack_overflow
(
  id int not null,
  title varchar(100) not null,
  created_at datetime2 null
)
go

-- show data
select * from stack_overflow
go
```

Next, we need to define our connection properties.

```
#
#  2 - Set connection properties
#

server_name = "jdbc:sqlserver://svr4tips2030.database.windows.net"
database_name = "dbs4tips2020"
url = server_name + ";" + "databaseName=" + database_name + ";"
user_name = "jminer"
password = "<your password here>"
table_name = "stack_overflow"
```

Last, we want to execute the code to write the dataframe.

```
#
#  3 - Write test dataframe
#

try:
  df.write \
    .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("truncate", True) \
    .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .option("user", user_name) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .save()
except ValueError as error :
    print("Connector write failed", error)
```

Executing a select query shows that the data was written correctly.

[image]

In short, look at the documentation for Spark SQL Types.  I found out that datetime2 works nicely.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.spark.sql.types?view=spark-dotnet

One word of caution, this code does not handle date time offset.  Also, there is no data type in Spark to use in an offset mapping.

```
# Sample date time offset value
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
user_timezone_setting = 'US/Pacific'
user_timezone = pytz.timezone(user_timezone_setting)
the_event = datetime.now() 
localized_event = user_timezone.localize(the_event)
print(localized_event)
```

The code above creates a variable with the following data.

[image]

But once we cast it to a dataframe, it loses the offset since it is converted to UTC time.  If UTC offset is important, you will have to pass that information as separate integer.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

SQLServer [datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) datatype has time range - `00:00:00 through 23:59:59.997`. output of `datetime.now()` will not fit in for datetime, you need to  change the datatype on SQLSever table to [datetime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: This is just one issue with the code sample above.